# 'cordova build android' not working

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to convert my angular app to android app using cordova by following this article - https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6

when I try to do the last step i.e 'cordova build android' I get the following error :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\Self Training\Cordova\demo\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradl
  e' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0
  >   or higher.

I have extracted tools, build-tools and platform-tools folders from android sdk downloader page into a folder called 'android-sdk' and had the following envirnment variable settings :

User Variables -> PATH - D:\Self Training\Cordova\android-sdk\tools;D:\Self Training\Cordova\android-sdk\platform-tools

System Variables -> ANDROID_HOME - D:\Self Training\Cordova\android-sdk

System Variables -> JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

System Variables -> Path - C:\Gradle\gradle-4.8.1\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Can some one please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cordova.gradle line 43 looked into the wrong directory. When I hardcoded and set the correct path, the build was successful

Answer (score 0):

You should add `D:\Self Training\Cordova\android-sdk\platform-tools` to the PATH **System variables**. Also, feel free to replace `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` with just `%JAVA_HOME%` in the same System's PATH variable.

Comment: I made the modifications as per your comment but still getting the same error :(

Comment: In cordova.gradle line 43 looked into the wrong directory. When I hardcoded and set the correct path, the build was successful

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried install android studio?
Guess that automatically install the build tool and everything u need there.

You could go [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install) and download the android studio

Hope this could help.

Comment: I have not installed Android Studio as I just wanted to convert angular app to android app instead of developing an android app from scratch. will try to do it by installing Android studio but wanted to learn by using just the command line tools instead of the entire Android Studio

Comment: yep, I just suggest you to install android studio.Then you can run the command line, I have some issue with the build tool before, and I just install android studio, they help me install all dependencies I needed in order to run Cordova command line

Comment: I have installed Android Studio and try to run the command line but am getting the same error. Is there any additional step to perform after installation of Android Studio? Please let me know

Comment: Android Studio is the last thing you need to develop Cordova applications. You cannot install a 1.5 GB IDE you don't need just because some environment variables are incorrectly set or missing.